# Share edits to "Master" Minecraft world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-worldedit

We're recreating the town we live in in Minecraft and would like to maintain a master copy of the town. Users can play in the map but not edit the master.

We've used Lidar for our topological source map but there's a lot of work to do in adding detail. We'd like others to contribute, such as by changing the appearances of buildings and making trees more realistic. It's only a small town (Blandford, Dorset) but changing the materials.

Is it possible to have this Master copy edited by multiple contributors simultaneously at different locations?

Comment: So basically have multiple people each working on the world individually and then coalesce the edits together?

Answer (score 3):

Well, in terms of integrated solutions... Well, there isn’t much you can do. However, you could reuse different things to form some sort of Version Control.

You could:

1. Just each have your own copy of the map and since none of the areas you are working in overlap, just WorldEdit or MCEdit the schematics of the modified parts in, or:
2. Use version control; start up a server and install an anti-griefing plugin like [CoreProtect](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/coreprotect.8631/) or [Logblock](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/logblock.67333/) and use its block and command tracking to roll back changes. This way, you can make changes directly together. Since you should all be admins, the anti-griefing side should not be a problem.

Finally, you should be using your server to make changes and then just simply running backups of that main world everytime you want a “release”.

tl;dr: **START A SERVER**